# Battery consumption needed for continuous speech recognition

Tags: android, speech-recognition, android-4.2-jelly-bean, battery

This might be duplicate but I couldn't find an answer for my question.

I am trying to develop a continuous speech recognition for Android device 4.1 and 4.2 but I am interested to know how much battery is consumed while the microphone is ON and the application with speech recognition is running? I haven't decide yet which one I will use like: [speech recognition API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html), Sphinx, Speex etc...

Can someone help me distinguish which solution would require less power consumption?

Comment: AFAIK, Speex is an audio codec, not particularly related to continuous speech recognition on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Predicting the battery consumption will be near impossible as it depends on several factors:

- The device's processing power
- The device's screen size, type and brightness
- The internet connection speed on the device (most speech recognition services send the data to a server)
- The efficiency of the hardware microphone
- Other background processes running on the device

Even if everything was in ideal conditions, the simple fact that different devices have different screens, processors and battery capacity will make it impossible to predict the consumption.

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is very useful! So based on your answer we can say that the app must be tested in order to measure the approximate battery consumption?

I am new to this technology therefore I wanted to know if there is a way to measure how the battery is performing if only this application is running on the device?

Comment: I used http://www.littleeye.co/ to profile the battery usage. Was very convenient. (_not_ the author)